# Gradient gets darker whenever leaving app and then coming back

Tags: swift, uikit, cagradientlayer

so I am implementing a simple gradient on the lower half a UIView subclass like the following[image]

however, every time I leave the app and reenter it, the gradient gets darker, and so forth. How do I make it so it just stays the same shade?[image]

Here is my code for the gradient. I don't know if its correct to place it in layoutSubviews, but I couldn't get it to work just by calling the gradient code directly, such as in viewDidLoad for example:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
   let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
   gradientLayer.type = .axial
   gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
   gradientLayer.frame = bounds
   gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
   gradientLayer.endPoint = .init(x: 0, y: 1)
   gradientLayer.zPosition = 1
   gradientLayer.opacity = 0.5
   layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
}
```

Comment: Are you adding multiple gradients on top of each other?

Comment: It because  layout method called every time and every time it create new layer and add sub layer. So you need to create and add sub layer inside the  awake from nib method and just update layer frame inside the layout subview method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`layoutSubviews()` gets called multiple times, so your gradient is getting added repeatedly.
`layoutSubviews()` is not really the place to be adding this gradient.  The reason adding it in `viewDidLoad()` was not working for you is because the `bounds` of the view haven't been established yet.  Go ahead and set up your gradient in `viewDidLoad()`.  Keep the `gradient` as a property, and use `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` to update the frame.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        gradientLayer.type = .axial
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = .init(x: 0, y: 1)
        gradientLayer.zPosition = 1
        gradientLayer.opacity = 0.5
        view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds
    }
}
```

---

For a view that is a subclass of `UIView`, you'd handle it like this:

```
class MyView: UIView {
    
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addGradient()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        addGradient()
    }
    
    func addGradient() {
        gradientLayer.type = .axial
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = .init(x: 0, y: 1)
        gradientLayer.zPosition = 1
        gradientLayer.opacity = 0.5
        layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you are saying. But how would you do it to just a view? I'm trying to add this to a custom UIView, which will then go into a separate view controller.